# Custom Set comparators for Set of Pairs in C++

Tags: c++, set

I have two sets, Set1, Set2. Both are sets of pairs(`pair <int,int>`).

Now for Set1, I want comparator like

```
set1Comparator(pair p1, pair p2)
{
      if(p1.first != p2.first)
              return p1.first < p2.first;
      else
              return p1.second < p2.second;
}
```

And for Set2, I want comparator like

```
 set2Comparator(pair p1, pair p2)
{
      if(p1.first != p2.first)
              return p1.first > p2.first;
      else
              return p1.second > p2.second;
}
```

Please, help. 
FYI, I checked so many links on c++ set comparator, but none of them could help me to define set-comparator for **specific** set.(Means if I define one comparator for set of pairs,then set1 and set2 will use same comparator, where set1 and set2 are set of pairs).

Comment: The constructor for std::set takes a comparison function as a parameter - see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius , I do agree with you, but I am still new learner. Content that is given on that website is very abstract, and out of my current understanding abilities, Thank you very much. From next time I will try, not to make such silly mistake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you declare a std::set you can specify the compare class, like

```
std::set< std::pair<foo,bar>, set1Comparator > myset1;
```

and then for the other set:

```
std::set< std::pair<foo,bar>, set2Comparator > myset2;
```

As simple as that :D